# Serializable Attribute Hangs VS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, session-state

I was implementing SQL Server Session State in MVC Application 4.8
All is okay but when I make one custom class as [Serializable] the VS Hangs and project does not loads.

Any inputs would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Clean solution> Run resolves the issue